# Xcode shows invalid debug summary for an object

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I have a simple object declaration:

```
@interface TSTask : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* otherValue;

@end
```

The weird thing happens during debug. I create a new TSTask, and then look at it in the variables area of the screen, and see

```
(TSTask *) 0 key/value pairs.
```

The TSTask object is not, nor has ever been an NSDictionary. But it wants to display it as such. To make matters worse, if I try and see the values of "name" and "otherValue", I can't. However, if I put in a "description" method, it does show me the values.

Any ideas how to correct this. It makes debugging really hard, when it doesn't display the right stuff.

Comment: That if you cage the name to something else such as `TSSTask`? 3rd parties should use a 3 character prefix in order to avoid Apple added classes.

Comment: I've been using 2-character prefixes for many years now. Apple's own docs say that a prefix consists of "two or three uppercase characters", and I don't see any recommendation about a 3-char prefix other than that. Also, if I were to have some name collision, wouldn't a linker-error get thrown?

Comment: Are you assigning this as the result of some network operation, and/or are you **certain** of the type when you do the assignment?

Comment: Apple has been adding classes with various two character prefixes rather consistently. Sure there will be an error but then the class will have to be re-named as well as classes using it. In the early days all Apple used was "NS" but that has changed.

Comment: I did try as @Zaph suggested, and renamed the class to something else, and that worked. What's annoying about this is that "Task" is the perfect name for this object. My only options are to come up with a different name, or come up with a different prefix, and rename all the classes in my app. It's only about 15 classes right now, but it's still annoying. Still have no idea why this particular name is causing grief, but I think I'm done trying to analyze it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I tried:

```
@interface TSTask : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* otherValue;
@end
@implementation TSTask
@end

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    TSTask *t = [TSTask new];
    NSLog(@"t: %@", t);
}
```

I have tried in both iOS and OSX and do not get the behavior you mention, I get the expected behavior.

[image]

So there must be something else: Can you post the usage at the point of error? Declaration, instantiation, etc.